# AzureML ParallelRunStep progress information

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

is there a way to know the progress percentage a ParallelRunStep has already computed on a pipeline?

As the total number of inputs is known in advance, I think it should not be hard to get this information.

This would be a great feedback for pipelines that takes long time to finish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from python azure sdk: *In Studio, if you go to the step's Metrics tab, you will be able to see a chart/table of execution progress, including remaining items, remaining mini batches, failed items, etc.*

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/18357